# Get all children in MySql

Tags: mysql, database

I have set up a simple test database that has two tables. The database is basically the description of a bunch of tasks. The two tables I have now are:

```
Task:
-Id
-Name
-Variables
```

And

```
SubtaskConnector:
-TaskId
-Order
-SubtaskId
```

A task can have subtasks, as the tables suggest. So task A can consist of task B and task C for example, this can go even deeper, task C can also consist of a task D and task E for example. How deep this goes, is initially unknown. It's just that I have one table to describe the general task and one table to describe the relation between the tasks.

The subtaskconnector has an "Order" column, this is here because it is important that the tasks are retrieved in the correct order. In the example above, task B cannot be put in front of task A. So here, the relation to task B will have number 0, and to task C it'll be 1. Since D is the first subtask of C, its order number will be 0 as well, and for E it would be 1.

The question that I have here is, how can I get all the tasks on the lowest level in correct order? I have some experience with SQL, but I honestly haven't got any idea on how I would go about making this. Say I just want the names, I would require the name of tasks B, D and E here, in that order.

Comment: this question could use an example of the desired output, but otherwise seems complete; I don't understand the close votes.

Comment: @ysth for a [mre] it needs more details and also a attempt.

Comment: @nbk while minimal reproducible examples are ideal and certainly make answering questions easier, their main point is to make sure the specification of the question is complete (and they don't always succeed at that).  here it already as complete as can be expected.  re attempt, this is in a class of questions where I at least don't expect that; if you don't know you need a recursive cte or that such a thing even exists, the most you can do is explain the problem; any attempt would be pointless.

Comment: "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only." makes no sense here; the question is very focused on a single problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easily accomplished with a recursive cte (requires mysql 8.0 or mariadb 10.2 or above).  (On earlier versions, you would need a stored procedure or a complex query with a join for each level of depth required.)

```
with recursive ordered_tasks (task_id, task_order) as (
    select task.id task_id, cast('' as char(800000)) task_order from task where task.id=1
    union all
    select subtask_connector.subtask_id task_id, concat(task_order,lpad(subtask_connector.ord,8,'0')) task_order
    from ordered_tasks
    join subtask_connector using (task_id)
)
select task.id,task.name,task.variables from ordered_tasks
join task on task.id=ordered_tasks.task_id
where not exists (select 1 from subtask_connector where subtask_connector.task_id=ordered_tasks.task_id)
order by ordered_tasks.task_order;
```

Note that you do need to provide length for the combined order field, which causes there to be a maximum supported depth, 100000 in this example.

In the query, I started with a specific root task id (1); you could instead select all tasks that are not subtasks of any other task, but you'd have to invent something to specify the initial order of those, since there is nothing in the data that would give relative order of root tasks.

I am assuming subtask connector orders are between 0 and 99999999.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f4fc1e2e9331b24e2b6f68551055a70)

Remove the where condition to include non-leaf tasks, which will then appear before their subtasks.  If non-leaf tasks need to appear after all their subtasks (and their subtasks), the cte would need to be modified to differentiate between leaf and non-leaf tasks in both parts of the union, giving non-leaf tasks an order of e.g. 'AAAAAAAA' and having subtasks replace the last part of the parent's order instead of just adding to it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I have some experience with SQL, but I had no clue recursion like this was actually possible. And yeah, I also don't know what these downvotes are... It says it's not focused on one problem, I don't know how this is too general tbh.

Comment: I have upvoted it, first thing after I tested it ;)

Comment: sorry, forgot it had a mystery downvote.  thanks!